# When I convert an email to html in c# the formatting on the email changes

Tags: c#, html, sql, email, format

I'm currently working on an equipment return eform, people input the equipment they're returning and when they click submit an email is sent to them and the equipment return team. I've also added a function where by when submit is clicked the programme accesses a database and brings up all the equipment that user still has yet to return. It then adds a grid view of the equipment they have yet to return to the email. To make the grid view show up on the email i had to convert the email to html, but when it does this it ruins the formatting of the email and puts it into one big paragraph instead of a few lines e.g.

(how I want it)
Hello

Bob Johnson has returned a laptop to Steve Johnson on the 28th of may

They also have these items taken out:

(How it comes out)

Hello Bob Johnson has returned a laptop to Steve Johnson on the 28th of may
They also have these items taken out:

below I have included the c# method I've used to send the email

```
  }
    protected void emailconfirmation(ObjectClass obIn_survey);
  try
        {
            s_Body += " Hello" + " \n\n" +
       "*************** \n" +
       ob_survey.ob_Name + " " + "has Returned a" + " " + ob_survey.ob_Description_of_Equipment + " " + ob_survey.ob_asset_number + " " + "to" + " " + ob_survey.ob_Returned_To + " " + "(Charger returned, " + ob_survey.Return_Charger + ")" + " on" + " " + ob_survey.ob_Date_of_Return.ToShortDateString() + " " + " \n\n" +
       " \n\n" + "Regards" + " \n\n" + "RCI Team" + " \n\n" + "This User also has the current Item(s) taken out";

            s_GridView = GetGridviewData(gv_Equipment);





            utility.Email_GenericMessage("RCITeam@rotherham.gov.uk", ob_survey.ob_Email_Receipt_to + ",RCITeam@rotherham.gov.uk", "Equipment Return", s_Body + s_GridView);

            edited the above line



        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Here is the method in the utility class

```
  public void Email_GenericMessage(String sIn_EmailFrom, String sIn_Emailto, String sIn_Subject, String sIn_Body )
    {
        using (MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(sIn_EmailFrom, sIn_Emailto, sIn_Subject, sIn_Body ))
        {
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (SmtpClient clt = new SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpServer"]))
            {
                clt.Send(msg);
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Use <br> instead of \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like it could be solved with a string replace.  Have you tried `s_Body.replace("\n", "<br/>");`? Since the message html new lines are represented as `<br/>` instead of \n.

Comment: This worked, thanks  a lot! I didn't think it would be this simple

Comment: @ELIOTRILEY if this worked for you please accept my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use .html layout and placeholder for creating emails.
It's most ease and correct way.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>{{NameFirst}}</div>
        <div>{{NameSecond}}</div>
        <div>{{Price}}</div>
        <div>{{InvoiceNumber}}</div>
    </body>
    </html>


    string forReplace = "{{" + prName + "}}";

    if (res.Contains(forReplace))
    {
        var prValue = item.GetValue(obj);

        res = res.Replace(forReplace, prValue.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot, to add just text a long side the variables "Price" etc is it just a case of adding another div with the text in quotation marks?               <div>"this person has"</div>